# Current umask of a process with <pid>

Tags: linux, procfs

Is it possible to get current umask of a process? From `/proc/<pid>/...` for example?

Comment: If you are not the faint of heart using gdb, there is a no-so-user-friendly way of getting this infor here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165212/linux-getting-umask-of-an-already-running-process

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Beginning with Linux kernel 4.7 ([commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3e42979e65dace1f9268dd5440e5ab096b8dee59)), the umask is available in `/proc/<pid>/status`.

```
$ grep '^Umask:' "/proc/$$/status"
Umask:  0022
```

Comment: This helped in RHEL 7.4!

Comment: Yes, and RHEL7.4 is 3.10.0, so I do not understand the comment about 4.7.

Comment: Right, some older kernels do not provide info about the umask, for example 2.6.18. However, the featureis  already there in 3.10.0. Thus, you should not say that this solution does not work before kernel 4.7.

Comment: Stéphane was kind enough to edit my post to link to the commit that clearly says when it was added, it's much newer than 3.10. Maybe it appeared much earlier in RHEL's patched kernel, but not yet in the mainline kernel, I don't know.

Comment: This worked for me with Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 18):

<sup>*Note: this answer applies to Linux kernels 4.6 and earlier. See [@egmont's answer](/a/354303) for newer versions of the kernel.*</sup>

The umask is not exposed in procfs. There was [an attempt](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/5/4/451) to add it without much success.

There is way to get the umask using `gdb`, as has been explained [here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165212/linux-getting-umask-of-an-already-running-process):

```
$ gdb --pid=4321
(gdb) call/o umask(0)
$1 = 077
(gdb) call umask($1)
$3 = 0
```

Keep in mind that gdb stops the process and its threads, so the temporary change of umask is negligible.

If that's good for your case, you can use this oneliner:

```
$ gdb --batch -ex 'call/o umask(0)' -ex 'call umask($1)' --pid=4321 2> /dev/null | awk '$1 == "$1" {print $3}'
077
```

Another alternative is, if you can control the running process, to write the umask to a file, an output or something similar and get it from there.

Comment: Just so this answer also shows up when googling those terms, it also explains _how to modify umask of running process_ (since getting it requires temporarily changing it). I initially dismissed it when searching this.

Comment: `(gdb) call/o umask(0)` gives me `'umask' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type`.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, with `systemtap` (as `root`), you could do

```
stap -e 'probe kernel.function("do_task_stat") {
           printf("%o\n", $task->fs->umask);
           exit()
         }
         probe begin {system("cat /proc/4321/stat>/dev/null")}'
```

Doing a `cat /proc/4321/stat` would trigger that probe on `do_task_stat` where we can access the `fs->umask` field of the corresponding process' `task_struct` in the kernel.